GUI freezes randomly
I am facing this odd issue in which GUI freezes randomly on button clicked
So basically This is the sample code:
void dialog::OnButton1Clicked()
{
    m_threadCmd = Button1; //Button1 is an enum from commandEnumList
    AfxBeginThread(ui_ThreadExecuteCmd, this);
}


UINT dialog::ui_ThreadExecuteCmd()
{
    OWaitCursor waitCursor;
    switch (this->m_threadCmd)
    {
    case BUTTON1:
    if (!Func1())
    {
       ShowError();
    }
    break;
    }
    this->m_threadCmd = 0;
    return 0;
}

bool Func1()
{
    //Notify GUI via PostMessage to disable the controls in the main thread
    //Do some processing
    //Notify GUI via PostMessage to enable the controls in the main thread
    //return errorcode
}

The weird thing is that sometime it works fine and sometimes the GUI freezes.
I am seeing the UI buttons getting disabled then performing the operation -then ui buttons getting enabled back again. The Gui freeze happens randomly after that and when it freezes the buttons become unclickable and i am not receiving any message in PreTranslateMsg() after the freeze for mouse click or anything else
Added logs to check if there is some deadlock happening, but does not seem so. Every function is getting hit and executed in the sequence that it needs to be. Still the GUI freeze happened.

Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship? You are effectively running into the same issue. Here's the solution: ALWAYS keep your UI code single-threaded. This is true across time and platforms. If you do need to update the UI from a non-UI thread you MUST schedule that update code to run on the UI thread (use messages or queue up an APC).

@IInspectable To add to your comment, it is important that the mainthread is the only one interacting with the UI elements. It is allowed to and even encouraged to run the business logic on background threads. Updating the UI from those threads then must be done by Posting messages back to the main thread

@PepijnKramer, Thats what i am doing here. I am running the process on the background thread then posting message to the main thread to do the UI stuff. The worker thread is doing nothing with the UI apart from Posting the message when the task is completed.

You're also changing the cursor shape from a non-UI thread. I'm positive that if we saw the code we'd easily find more violations.

OWaitCursor waitCursor; is a GUI action on a background thread.  ShowError(); if it actually shows an error is a GUI event on a background thread.  Too much missing code called in the background thread ( eg Func1 ) for this question to be concidered a [mcve].

Does AfxBeginThread(ui_ThreadExecuteCmd, this); even compile? AfxBeginThread() takes a free function pointer, not a class member function. Maybe it could, if you make it static - in that you couldn't use this in the function though. And the thread function has an application-defined LPVOID "parameter".

Your code is not an MRE, it does not show the implementation of ShowError (which if it shows a dialog IS running a UI element from a background thread). Nor does your code show any posting of a message (or WM_PAINT, or Invalidate message)
